# Word for graph that counts backwards vs graph that counts forwards

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry if the title was confusing. I am having difficulty putting this simply, so let

Let's say we're graphing sales per week as a line graph.

You can count forwards, in which case, if viewing on a Sunday, it would appear as though sales are down this week, and through the week, it would move up until the end of the week.

Or you can count backwards. In this case, the last data point (this week) is exactly 7 days of data, and so forth all the way to the start.

What is the name for these two types of graphs?

Comment: Maybe one shows calendar week data, and the other shows 7-day sliding/rolling/moving window data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first graph is a *[running total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total)* that resets weekly.
Your second graph is a *[rolling sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)*, also called a *moving sum*.  From the linked page on Wikipedia:

> In financial applications a simple moving average (SMA) is the unweighted mean of the previous n data.

This can clearly be extended to other operations, such as a "moving sum" from your example.

Comment: Also, these are what I call those sorts of graphs in my role as a data visualization expert for my company; @Jim mentioned "moving window", and the functions that calculate these types of values are often referred to as "Window" functions..